# Vue.js: Use this.$route.params.id from data in computed functions

Tags: vue.js

Currently I have this code that works:

```
computed: {
    filteredMovies: function () {
      return this.movies.filter(movie => movie.director.id === 1);
    },
  },
```

Instead, I'm trying to use `this.$route.params.id` from data in computed function, like this:

```
computed: {
    filteredMovies: function () {
      return this.movies.filter(movie => movie.director.id === this.$route.params.id);
    },
  },
```

```
data: function () {
    return {
      directorId: this.$route.params.id,
      movies: [....],
    };
  },
```

I'm getting no errors, but I'm getting empty list of movies. :(

How can I achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: make directorId as a computed property and pass that instead of this.$route.params.id
___
directorId() {
   return this.$route.params.id
}

Comment: before the return statement can you try printing the 'this.$route.params.id' and see if its containing the value

Comment: if yes then check if its a number or a char and let me know

Comment: Yes, that works. I can print it before the return statement. It is a number. Could you please specify how to adjust the function? many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the id as a prop by setting "props: true" in your route definition
Ex:

```
{ path: '/movie/:id', component: Movie, props: true }
```

Then in your component you juste need to add the id prop and use it:

```
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredMovies() {
      return this.movies.filter(movie => movie.director.id === this.id);
    },
  },
```